# Chrome loading really slowly on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, performance

I just got Windows 10 and I've noticed that Chrome takes a really long time to load when I just click the icon.  If, however, I right-click and choose the New Window "Task" it launches almost immediately.

Here's a screencapture:  https://youtu.be/Ijglek5-MyQ

Anybody know why this is and what could be done to fix it?

Things I've tried:

- Create a new chrome profile.
- Close chrome (closing window with new
  profile last so that chrome will load it on next launch)
- Launch chrome as before.
- Problem still persists.